# Save UICollectioView user progress [Swift]

Tags: swift

I have a simple collectionView with images, and I need to save user's current image so when they leave the app or the selected gallery and back again they can complete scrolling from where they left off. I read about the user defaults but I want the user to be able to continue the scrolling from different devices how I can do that? this is my code:

```
class GalleryViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,  UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIScrollViewDelegate  {

   
     private lazy var databaseService = DatabaseService()
     private var listener: ListenerRegistration?
     private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    

    
    private var photo = [Photos]() {
      didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    
    private var gallery: Gallery
    init?(coder: NSCoder, gallery: Gallery) {
      self.gallery = gallery
      super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

     
        
    }
    
    
     override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionViewLayout()
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
            
   
     }

     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(true)
            
       self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
            
          
            listener = Firestore.firestore().collection(DatabaseService.galleriesCollection)
              .document(gallery.galleryId)
              .collection(DatabaseService.photoCollection)
              .addSnapshotListener({ [weak self] (snapshot) in
              } else if let snapshot = snapshot {
                let photos = snapshot.documents.map { Photos($0.data()) }
                self?.photo = photos
              }
            })
            }
  
    
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return photo.count
         }


     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell

      
         let photos = photo[indexPath.row]
         cell.setupCell(for: photos)
         return cell
     }



     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

  return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width), height: (collectionView.frame.size.height))
        }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to work across multiple devices, you are right, you can't use UserDefaults. You have to save the current scrolling position on the server(which in your case I suppose `Firebase`).

When loading your view, you have to fetch the saved position, and scroll the `UICollectionView`. You can use your current request for that:

```
let photos = snapshot.documents.map { Photos($0.data()) }
self?.photo = photos // According to your code this will reload the CollectioView
let position = // Fetch saved position 
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: position, section: 0)
self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: [.centeredVertically, .centeredHorizontally], animated: true)
```

I suppose you do not have more than one section in your `UICollectionView`, but if so, you can easily save and retrieve the section index also using the above logic.

And now we only need to save the position every time the user ends it's scroll:

```
// User initiated scrolls
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if !scrollView.isTracking, !scrollView.isDragging, !scrollView.isDecelerating { // 1
        scrollViewDidEndScrolling(scrollView)
    }
}
 // Programatically initiated scrolls
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if !decelerate, scrollView.isTracking, !scrollView.isDragging, !scrollView.isDecelerating { // 2
        scrollViewDidEndScrolling(scrollView)
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndScrolling(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let visibleCells = collectionView.visibleCells
    if let firstCell = visibleCells.first {
         if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: firstCell as UICollectionViewCell) {
            // you can now save the indexPath
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, I've 3 errors here ===> if let firstCell = visibleCells.first() ==> error (Type of expression is ambiguous without more context) there is line under first...  let position =   ==> error (Expected initial value after '=')

Comment: and here ==>   if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: collectionCell as UICollectionViewCell) => error (Cannot find 'collectionCell' in scope) I tried to add my custom cell but I got error too

Comment: thank you again. there is no errors now but the code doesn't work. I don't know if it's because i added zero to ( let position = 0) there was error her telling me i have to add initial value. Or do i have to add more code after (if let indexPath = collectionView...)?

Comment: @Wonhu What do you mean by the code is not working ? After if `let indexPath = collectionView` you should update your position and call call a request to save it on the sever.

Comment: I lunched the app in the simulator and when i leave the gallery and reopens it it starts from the beginning. Sorry I'm a beginner i don't know how to update the position and call request

Comment: @Wonhu here you can read how to read and write to Firebase storage: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write